# Why was my question concerning the existence of a word put on hold?

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked a question here [Is there a word for somebody who likes to be taken care of and pampered?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409222/is-there-a-word-for-somebody-who-likes-to-be-taken-care-of-and-pampered) and it was put on hold because of the following,

"Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: About single word requests"

However, I *did* explain how the word will be used. I said a word with that meaning **which does not have any negative connotation**. The rule above does not say I should provide a sentence. It simply asks to give details of the usage which is exactly what I did. So why was it put on hold?

Comment: Click on the link "see: About single word requests". It says, nay shouts out loud, "YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE" :)

Comment: @NVZ Thanks I should have clicked on the linking before asking :\

Comment: Uh, yeah. So you might want to delete this meta-question since it's a waste of time

Comment: Hover your mouse over the tag, and when the pop-up window appears, click the *info* link. It gives you more guidelines on how to write good single-word requests.

Comment: @Clare It wasn't a waste of time for the OP. They're now better informed.

Comment: @Clare nothing is a waste of time as long as you learn something from it. :)

Comment: Your question (es edited by you to include relevant examples)  is now better than a great many single-word requests that are currently open on the site. I imagine that it will be reopened shortly.